# mysql inner join and where

Tags: mysql, sql

2 tables: `employee` & `employee_address` as an example

three indexes are provided:

```
ALTER TABLE employee ADD INDEX `E_P` (`position`) USING BTREE;

ALTER TABLE employee_address ADD INDEX `EA_Z` (`zipcode`) USING BTREE;

ALTER TABLE employee_address ADD INDEX `EA_E` (`employee_id`) USING BTREE;
```

1st inner join

```
select * from employee_address ea
inner join employee e on e.employee_id = ea.employee_id and e.position = 'MANAGER'
where ea.zipcode > 30000
```

2nd inner join with where clause

```
select * from employee_address ea
inner join (
select * from employee e where e.position = 'MANAGER'
) e on e.employee_id = ea.employee_id 
where ea.zipcode > 30000
```

assume there are :
500000 records in each table
1000 different position
2000 different zipcode

I found query 1 is much more efficient.

What's different between this 2 queries?

Would it be possible to query it as fast as they were in just one table?
and How?

```
select * from employee e where e.position = 'MANAGER' 
and e.zipcode > 30000

ALTER TABLE employee ADD INDEX `Z_P` (`zipcode`, `position`) USING BTREE;
```

Comment: USe `EXPLAIN` to see the different query plans.

Comment: You should show the explain plan output use explain before select to get the output.

Comment: @flyshell . . . MySQL has a tendency to materialize subqueries in the `FROM` clause, and that limits use of indexes on those tables.

Comment: explain is examized, however I could'nt find a soluiton to match the performance of query 3

Answer (score 1):

On the second one you are prefiltering and then joining. This breaks the index.
You are basically returning a new table on which to join which has no index.

If you look at the query explain plan you should see that the join in n2. does not have an index lookup.

It's generally a good idea, if you want to check what's slowing you down to use the query explain plan and learn to read what it is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Looking to your code sample,instead of the index you proposed, you could try using  these composite index

```
ALTER TABLE employee_address ADD INDEX ea_id_z (employee_id, zipcode) ;
ALTER TABLE employee ADD INDEX E_P (position, employee_id) ;

select * 
from employee_address ea
inner join employee e on e.employee_id = ea.employee_id 
and e.position = 'MANAGER'
    and ea.zipcode > 30000
```

In a query the db engine use  a single index for each table so you should provide the index most selective and with much info needed during the where/join clause evaluation
Thne the use of proper composite index is most efficient

For a index in better add the most macthing column at left side (in this case position instead of zipcode  because manager use a equal operator )

for the secondo query based on join with subquery  the result of the subquery is managed as a temporary table the index are used  for the inner select but are not useful for the join clause (in this case only the index for outer table can be used )

Comment: In newer versions of mariadb and I believe also MySQL, every non-primary index is automatically a composite index, with the primary key columns implicitly added.  Though possibly not with myisam.

Comment: no  ..  a composite index  in not automatically .. created  .. a composite index is an index that involve more then a column ...and are  not craeted automatically   you comment is not clear to and is not clear how this is related  to my answer ..probably you are referring to some constraints ..

Comment: No, I mean just what I say.  If you have an index foo (bar) and a primary key (baz,quux), foo will actually be an index on (bar,baz,quux)

Comment: @ysth yep, that's my understanding too for InnoDB tables

Comment: even ea_id_z is used, it only make query e fast.
however if the result is huge (millions records).
the reuslt will be a temp table for querying ea which is slow?
it is still slower than [query 3]?

Comment: @flyshell    .. you comment is not clear  to me  ..  the performace are improved  i a significant way or not?? ... I don't understand the question related  to miliions recors .. for the question about query 3  ... this query in not the same as  the others  ..  query 3 have not JOIN  ..  is a simgle table query ..

Comment: @scaisEdge in query_3 it has a comp-index (position, zipcode) while in query_1 position and zipcode are  in different tables.

in query1.  the inner join has the result of all [MANAGER] employee, it has all differnet kind of zipcodes which are not indexed. if the result of inner join is huge, it will takes time to get zipcode > 30000

Comment: you should study better how index  work really ... https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html